# Is it possible to get values of items in adjacent table rows with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have items in a table like this

```
<td></td>
<td><input class="form-control" value="$title"></td>
<td><textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5">$tdesc</textarea><td>
<td><a href="#savems" class="svMS btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="33334">Save</a></td>
```

I am using the following javascript to get the ID of the button that is clicked.

```
$("a[href=#savems]").click(function() {
    var id;
    if ($(this).hasClass('svMS')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

I wish to send the other table items to a server for processing, is there a way in javascript to select the corresponding items?

Comment: and how do that table relate to currently clicked element?

Comment: The tds in the example are in a tr, and you want trs before and/or after this tr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Get the parent tr first and then their inner values using respective selectors.

```
$("a[href=#savems]").click(function() {
        var id;
        if ($(this).hasClass('svMS')) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(id);
    var title = $(this).closest('tr').find('.form-control').val();
    var tdesc = $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').val();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
   <tr id="row1">
       <td>Some data</td>
       <td>Some Data</td>
       <td>Some Data</td>
       <td id="save-row1">Save</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now the js:

```
$("[id^=save]").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var rowid=id.split("-")[1];

    var col1_val=$("#"+rowid +" td:nth-child(1)").html();
    var col2_val=$("#"+rowid +" td:nth-child(2)").html();
    var col3_val=$("#"+rowid +" td:nth-child(3)").html();
 })
```